# On OSX "El capitan" also signed GDB don't run

Tags: macos, gdb, osx-elcapitan

Today I installed from `macports` the `gdb debugger;` following all the documents on the net I've signed `GDB` with a self signed certificate for code signing.

Despite that `gdb` don't run with the usual error:

```
`Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 1217: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
(please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))`
```

If running `gdb` with `sudo` it works fine.

Two clues:

1. When signing I was compelled to `sudo`, otherwise:

   `/opt/local/bin/ggdb: replacing existing signature
   error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains /XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate: can't create output file: /opt/local/bin/ggdb.cstemp (Permission denied)
   /opt/local/bin/ggdb: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used`
2. I verified the signature with:

   `codesign --verify --verbose=9 /opt/local/bin/ggdb`

and the result is:

```
`/opt/local/bin/ggdb: valid on disk
/opt/local/bin/ggdb: satisfies its Designated Requirement`
```

and with:

```
codesign --display --verbose=9 /opt/local/bin/ggdb

Executable=/opt/local/bin/ggdb
Identifier=org.gnu.gdb
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=42012 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1309+2 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=fcdc413a6e9a46c43dbf5a6bef10dfc9ca859139
CandidateCDHash sha256=299f6ddc02c908d00f2ec0e858cff9ff44732f03
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
-2=9181fb83a0797cdc555934e7e0b1ae35e91cf32040ebf25af11bf5bc1f1c5947
[Lots of hex...]
1307=6720981bf5bd01662bf60c634c900bc93bc5c4628db492f2865f17b7316eb0ef
1308=04de6d07a1d252c0f5b88640956b83a4d77594d7f175929c486434abea1e99c1
CDHash=299f6ddc02c908d00f2ec0e858cff9ff44732f03
Signature size=1745
Authority=gdb-cert
Signed Time=2-giu-2016, 16:11:02
Info.plist entries=4
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=88
```

Any clue to solve this issue will help a lot!

Thank you.